# Ionic Lifecycle: ionViewDidLoad

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using this hook on my Home to get and store some data for my app.

In many articles and tutorials over the net is been sad the ***ionViewDidLoad*** hook will fire only **ONCE** after the view is cached.

But I tested switching pages with `navCtrl.setRoot` then go back to Home...

The *ionViewDidLoad* is called again. Did I understand it all wrong? Am I doing it wrongly? I should put a "test" before my commands on *ionViewDidLoad*?

Any help or explanation for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ionViewDidLoad` **does** get called only per page creation. This view is cached when navigation occurs through `push()` i.e this page is still there in the stack. If navigation happens back to this page via `pop()`, the hook is not called again.

You are currently using `setRoot()` to test. This will **clear the navigation stack** i.e all views are in the current stack are destroyed. The current view is also destroyed when you call `pop()` on the current page.

Check View Creation and Lifecycle hook section in the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)